# Using mRMRe in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, feature-selection

I am currently working on a project where I have to do some feature selection for building a predictive model. I was lead to a package in R called `mRMRe`. I am just trying to work the example but cannot get it working. The example can be found here - http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/mRMRe/docs/mRMR.ensemble.

Here is my code -

```
data(cgps)
data <- data.frame(target=cgps.ic50, cgps.ge)
mRMR.ensemble(data, 1, rep.int(1, 30))
```

When I run this code I get the error -

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : data must be of type mRMRe.Data.
```

I dug a litter further and found that you actually have to convert the data to `mRMR.Data` type. So I did this update -

```
# Update
data <- mRMR.data(data = data.frame(target=cgps.ic50, cgps.ge))
mRMR.ensemble(data, 1, rep.int(1, 30))
```

but I still get the same error. When I look at the class I have -

```
> class(data)
[1] "mRMRe.Data"
attr(,"package")
[1] "mRMRe"
```

So the data is the requested type but the code is still not functional.

My question is if anyone has experience using this package or any help or comments would be appreciated!

Also want to note that in the example from the link - when I load the data

```
cgps_ic50 -> cgps.ic50
cgps_ge -> cgps.ge
```

so the names of the data aren't the same as the same in the example.

Comment: `cgps_ge` and `cgps_ic50` throw "objects not found" errors. I get the same error as do you with your code, but I do not get an error running the example code in the package documentation. Looks to me that you have not been "reading the manual".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the code you wrote:

```
data(cgps)
data <- mRMR.data(data = data.frame(target=cgps.ic50, cgps.ge))
mRMR.ensemble(data, 1, rep.int(1, 30))
```

The function mRMR.ensemble is getting the data as the first parameter, but the default first parameter in this function is solution_count.

I understand that your intentions executing that example are finding 30 relevant and non-redundant features using the classic mRMR feature selection algorithm so try this:

```
data(cgps)
data <- mRMR.data(data = data.frame(target=cgps.ic50, cgps.ge))
mRMR.ensemble(data = data, target_indices = 1, 
              feature_count = 30, solution_count = 1)
```

The target_indices are the positions in the original data.frame of the features used to maximize the relevance (correlation or other quality measure for this issue), so features selected in the end will be good for explaining the features indicated in the target_indices.
For example, in a classification problem, we would choose the position of the class variable as the value for the target_indices parameter.

The feature_count parameter indicates the number of variables to be chosen.

The solution_count is not a parameter of the classic mRMR. It indicates the number of mRMR algorithms to be ensembled to get a final feature selection, so if set to 1 it performs only one classic mRMR.